# Syntax error near unexpected token `(' no matter what code I run

Tags: c

I'm getting this error for all my codes, even the ones that were testing properly before.

Even the most basic codes like this gives me that error. Did I change my emacs setting
somehow? I have no idea what's going on...

> ./te.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token '('
>
> ./te.c: line 3: `int main ()'

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main () {

 printf ("Welcome to C!\n");    return 0;


 }
```

Please help!!!

Comment: what is the `e` at the end?

Comment: This code runs fine, http://ideone.com/Fcx9lU

Comment: sorry i just edited my question. i compile with gcc te.c and gives me no errors. when i run with ./te.c it gives me the error.

Comment: LOL!  You don't run `./te.c`!   That is your source code.  You are supposed to run `./a.out` which is the executable output of your compiler!

Comment: it ran fine for me a couple of hours ago but i think i changed the setting on my emacs or terminal... i have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: See **[Example 1: Compiling a simple program](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html)**

Comment: @abelenky, make an answer for it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't run `./te.c`
That is your source code.

You are supposed to run `./a.out` which is the executable output of your compiler!

Recommend you read up on **[Example 1: Compiling a simple program](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html)**